# Entity Framework 6 Adding foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship

I have a model

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Consumer
{
    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set;}
}
```

The problem I have is when you create a `Consumer` object and reference existing `Order`, is there a way to just pass the Order ID and allow entity framework to do the rest.

The only way I could get it to work is the following:

```
//Look up order
var order = dbContext.Order.Where(x=>x.ID == orderID)
var consumer = new Consumer { new List{ order} };
dbContext.Consumer.Add(consumer);
```

Is there a way to do this without the looking up the order? Example by just plugging in the order Key? Something like this:

```
var consumer = new Consumer {
    new List { 
       new Order { ID = orderID } 
    } 
};
dbContext.Consumer.Add(consumer);
```

Note: the big difference is that I just pass the "orderID" and don't have to actually pass the whole `Order` object.

**Update**:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Order> InheritedOrders{ get; set;}
}
```

in `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityClass>().HasMany(x=>x.InheritedOrders).WithMany().Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("ParentID");
                cs.MapRightKey("ChildID");
                cs.ToTable("OderInheritance");
            });
}
```

In this case, how would it work since your reference an object of the same ype and your using a auto generated `WithMany` generated table?

Thanks,
D

Comment: Yes, attach `new Order { ID = orderID }` to the context as `Unchanged`.

Comment: what do you mean by "Uncahnged".  I tried doing this and the relationship was never created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a self-relationship (1:n) like this:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentOrderId{ get; set; }

    public virtual Order ParentOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> ChildOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .HasOptional(i => i.ParentOrder)
    .WithMany(i => i.ChildOrders)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentOrderId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Insert Order (As @sgtrice1 said):

```
var order = new Order 
{
    Name = "Order 1",
    ParentOrderId = 1 // FK HERE, IT WILL MAKE THE RELATIONSHIP
};
dbContext.Order.Add(order);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wasn't the question.....And what you stated is what I already said in my question.  The question is how do you actually add the relationship without doing a fetch for the db object.  I'm not asking how you make the relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to have a reference key in the order model.  like so:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ConsumerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Consumer Consumer { get; set; }
}

public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer()
    {
        this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set;}
}
```

Then you can add the Consumer without an order.

```
var consumer = new Consumer { };
dbContext.Consumer.Add(consumer);
```

Later when you add the Order you can attach the Consumer like so...

```
var order = new Order {
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Order 1",
    ConsumerId = 1
};
dbContext.Order.Add(order);
```

And query it back like so...

```
foreach (Order order in Consumer.Orders)
{
    // do something with each order.
}
```

**UPDATE**

With your above question I'm assuming you mean how do you find the child orders?  If you use the code Fabio provided you could fetch the records like so...

```
foreach (var order in Consumer.Orders.ChildOrders)
{
    // Do something with the child orders
}
```

or nested

```
foreach (var order in Consumer.Orders)
{
    // parent order

    foreach (var childOrder in order.ChildOrders)
    {
        // child orders of parent.
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you handle the case where you reference a list of object of the same type.  I updated my question with the example. Thanks